# JQuery traversal, trouble using .next() correctly

Tags: jquery

Could someone explain to me why .next() is not working as I expect it to in this example:

HTML Structure

```
<p>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#q1">Question 1 Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#q2">Question 2 Link</a></li>
  </ol>
</p>
<p>
  <a name = "q1"></a><div>Question 1... <br /> Answer 1...</div>
  <a name = "q2"></a><div>Question 2... <br /> Answer 2...</div>
</p>
```

Jquery (Purpose is to highlight the question+answer div relating to the link which was clicked on)

```
$(function() {      
    $('a').click(function(){
        href = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        target = $('a[name="'+href+'"]').next('div');
        // For simplicity in the example, I will simply highlight in red.                        
        target.css('background-color', 'red');
    }); 
});
```

However this isn't working. If I place a `console.log(target.html())` in the code I find that it returns `null`.

Any suggestions on how I can find the `<div>` which appears immediately after `<a name="..."></a>`.

Comment: What about the `$('a[name="'+href+'"]')` selector? Does that return the a tag you're after?

Comment: Add this to a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) for easy reproduction of this and debugging and sharing of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question. But instead of using named anchors you could give the `div`s the corresponding ID:

```
<div id="q1">Question 1... <br /> Answer 1...</div>
<div id="q2">Question 2... <br /> Answer 2...</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function(){                 
    $(this.href).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

IDs on elements works the same as named anchors.

---

Your jQuery code itself looks correct (also with respect to the HTML). But I suspect that the browsers are correcting the generated DOM somehow as (afaik) `div` elements are not allowed inside `p` elements.

**Update:** Seems I'm correct (more or less), [at least Chrome produces this](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/v453q/) (inspect the DOM):

```
<p>
    <a name="q1"></a>
</p>
<div>Question 1... <br> Answer 1...</div>
<a name="q2"></a>
<div>Question 2... <br> Answer 2...</div>
<p></p>
```

You can see that the first `a` element has no next sibling. It should work for the second one though.

Comment: Absolutely.  Based on the HTML 4 spec, it is legal to use an achor tag to [point to an ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

Comment: You were right, the reason was because of there being `<div>` elements inside of a `<p>` element. Thanks for the help and quick solution.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion; the HTML code is incorrect, so the browser does it's best to produce a correct DOM from it, causing the actual elements to be different from the HTML code. Firefox does the same correction as Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution that didn't involve anchors & ids.

This plugin looks for the next occurrence in the whole DOM, not just siblings - I think the way you originally expected.

In other words, if you were looking at the markup, what's the next tag you'd see that matches the selector:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.subsequent = function(selector) {  
    var subsequent = $();       
    this.parents().andSelf().each(function() {
      $(this).nextAll().each(function(){

          //check self
          subsequent = $(this).filter(selector);
          if(subsequent.length > 0) return false;   

          //check kids
          subsequent = $(this).children(selector);
          return subsequent.length == 0;                
      });
      return subsequent.length == 0;   
    });
    return subsequent.first();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg6rZ/1/)

This only selects the *first* occurrence. You may want to make a `subsequentAll` version to match all subsequent occurrences.